# Automatically generate a new page / URL in ASP.Net / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I want to generate a new URL and page when someone submits a form. Meaning when the button is clicked, a new asp.net page is added to a folder.

I think maybe Routing does this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

But is this the way to do it or is there some other tutorial/way to be doing this?

Comment: Routing is precisely what you're after. [Here is a tutorial that goes into some detail on it](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing). And for more complex and [custom routes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwic8_Wk76nJAhUWKogKHcgIDHsQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asp.net%2Fmvc%2Foverview%2Folder-versions-1%2Fcontrollers-and-routing%2Fcreating-custom-routes-cs&usg=AFQjCNHbCF8wmumQoBGWR0R1aS3vUZPdeQ&sig2=Vi_hKIc3RnkKwV1MaWwuCw&cad=rja)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to create a new aspx page for each page submission.

But what you have to do is create an aspx page that handles these form submissions, each submission has a different URL or Query string.

You can use the IIS URL Rewrite module.

check this URL http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1):

basically generating a page is not something that can be done by a user. most of the time routing can be the answer of your question. the parameters that page recieves can have different content based on those parameters. like beliw:
you send parameter by:

```
Redirect("page.aspx?name=john" );
```

recieve in other page:

```
string x= Request.queryString["name"];
```

it is mostly used in cms systems. for example you just have one news page but the prameter that page recieves says to show which news from database.